# ¿Como logro un onclick dentro de append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Intento hacer una acción `onclick` dentro de un `append`. Aquí esta mi ejemplo:

```
$('#tr').append("<td><a onclick='nombre(a,b)'></a></td>")
```

al darle click en el `link` quiero que pase algunos parámetros. Ya lo intente así. Hice mi función así:

```
function nombre(a,b){}
```

pero no logro que funcione. Tal vez no es la manera correcta. Necesito ayuda! Si alguien me puede explicar mas en detalle como solucionar este problema.

Comment: has probado a poner un alert() dentro de tu función **nombre(a,b){ alert();}** a ver que ocurre?

Comment: Si, igual que console.log()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

un ejemplo usando Jquery puedes capturar todos los click de los botones cuya clase sea botones

```js
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td><button class="botones">Nombre del boton</button></td></tr>');
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td><button class="botones">Super Boton</button></td></tr>');
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td><a class="botones">href 1</a></td></tr>');
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td><a class="botones">href 2</a></td></tr>');
$(".botones").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
//tu funcion con los parametros
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function nombre(a,b)
  {
    ...
  }
  $('#tr').append("<td><a class='btn'></a></td>")
  $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    nombre(a,b);
  });
});
```

No necesitas cambiar tu tag a por button.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

No es la mejor forma de hacerlo por lo siguiente:

- El append tiene que parsear todo el HTML que le pasas como string y entre más grande sea el string más te va a pegar en el rendimiento.
- La función que le estas pasando al onclick necesita las variables **a** y **b** como parametros, sin embargo al crear el evento se van a perder los valores de esas variables, a menos que sean variables globales.
- El mantenimiento va a ser tedioso

Toma en cuenta que al no ponerle un texto al anchor (el link) no habrá un elemento al cual darle click

Puedes crear cada elemento por separado y de esa forma podrás manipularlos como mejor te convenga

```js
function agregaLink(){
  var a = "Hola";   //a puede ser local
  var b = "Mundo";  //b puede ser local
  var td;
  var link;

  //Creamos el anchor con el texto 'click aqui' y el evento click que invoca a nombre(a,b)
  link = $("<a>").html("click aqui").click(function(){ nombre(a,b) });
  //Creamos el td y le agregamos el anchor
  td = $("<td>").append(link);
  //Al elemento con id='tr' le agregamos el td
  $('#tr').append(td);
}

function nombre(a,b){
   console.log(a+" "+b);
}

$(document).ready(function(){ agregaLink(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr"> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con una etiqueta button:

```
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td><button onclick="nombre()">Nombre del boton</button></td></tr>');

#tabla = id de la tabla
```

Intenta creando una funcion y mandado datos en duro onclick="nombre(1)"

```
function nombre(valor){
    alert(valor);
}
```

Con  esto compruebas que tu onclick esta funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Y si cambias esto:

```
$('#tr').append("<td><a onclick='nombre(a,b)'></a></td>")
```

Por esto. Si vas a tener varios append, usa una clase "enlace-td" en lugar de un id:

```
$('#tr').append("<td><a id='enlace-td' data-param0="dato1" data-param1="dato2"></a></td>")
$("#enlace-td").click(nombre);
```

Para la función nombre:

```
function nombre(ev) {
    // currentTarget apunta al propio elemento al que enlazaste el evento.
    var param0 = $(ev.currentTarget).attr("data-param0"),
    param1 = $(ev.currentTarget).attr("data-param1");
    console.log(param0);
    console.log(param1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no tiene errores pero podrías estar confundiendo algunas cosas.

1. Veo que utilizas un selector de **ID** cuyo nombre es igual que su **TAG**, ya que no muestras el código **HTML** esto tiende a
   confundir.
2. Utilizas las variables `a` y `b` pero no veo donde las defines.

Por lo demás tu código esta correcto, te dejo un ejemplo funcional para que compares con el tuyo donde coloco los puntos: **IMPORTANTE!!** de tal forma puedas ver donde esta el error.

Ejemplo:

```js
// IMPORTANTE!! Definir las variables a y b
var a,b;

$('tr').append("<td><a onclick='nombre(a,b)'>Link</a></td>");

function nombre(a,b){
 console.log("hola"); // IMPORTANTE!! acción a realizar en la función
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr id="tr"><!-- IMPORTANTE!! definir el id="tr" -->
 </tr>
</table>
```